# C++: Decimal to Roman Numeral conversion

Tags: c++, string-conversion

I know how to do this and have made a program that does so in the past, however it never incorporated the special cases of roman numerals (e.g. IV = 4). Integrating that into a functional program in a minimalistic way is my main problem. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: If you know [how to read them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#Reading_Roman_numerals) it should be easy to create them as well. It's just division, modulo and in loop do string concatenating specific strings to another string.

Comment: Well yes but what's an example? I know how to read to them, it's just difficult trying to apply special cases. I'm probably just overthinking the process, but I'd just like to know what to do. What was your implementation if I may ask @JoachimPileborg?

Comment: Using a table of all one- and two-"digit" numerals and their values, you can search from M (1000) to I (1) for the first value >= the value you want to convert. Concatenate that string to the result and subtract the corresponding value. Repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *very* simple solution, in pseudo-code, could look something like this:

```
value = get_the_value_to_convert();
divider = 1000;  // Start at 1000 (M)

while (value > 0)
{
    count = value / divider;
    value = value % divider;

    for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        print(roman_numeral_from_number(divider));

    divider /= 10;
}
```

The `roman_numeral_from_numbe` function does a one-to-one mapping between a number and a roman numeral.

For e.g. `5432` as input it would print `MMMMMCCCCXXXII`.

For better results, divide the `divider` variable with `2` and `5` every second time.

For even better results, add check for certain numbers, like `90` being equal to `"XC"`.

Note that even with the modifications, the above algorithm can't handle very large numbers, but on the other hand [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#Large_numbers) states that historically it was only used for small numbers anyway.

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot! For the "roman_numeral_from_number" method, would that look something like `value >= 1000 ? roman_year += "M" : ...`?

Comment: Also, you're not even using that `i` variable in the loop, so you technically don't even need the loop statement or the count variable.